# Find all Cloud Services (Classic) which are stopped or have no deployments

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-cloud-services

I'm trying to write a script that will give me a list of unused Cloud Services in Azure. Unused, I mean which are stopped or have no deployments.

I figure out how to do it with App Services, but stuck with Cloud Services, because of classic model. I believe it requires different methods to call its properties, etc.

Could someone help me there to dig, or what methods, cmdlets to use to get these properties?

Thanks in advance!

I thought it would have something similar:

```
    function check_site {
Write-Output "------------------------------------------"
Write-Output "Microsoft.Web/sites"
Write-Output "------------------------------------------"
$RT = "Microsoft.Web/sites"
$apps = Get-AzureRmResource -ODataQuery "`$filter=resourcetype eq 'Microsoft.Web/sites'"
foreach($app in $apps){
    $full_app = Get-AzureRmResource -ResourceGroupName $app.ResourceGroupName -ResourceType $RT -ResourceName $app.Name
    if("Running" -ne $full_app.Properties.state)
    {
        $1 = Get-AzureRmResource -ResourceGroupName $app.ResourceGroupName -ResourceType $RT -ResourceName $app.Name | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
        'App Service: ' + $1
    }
}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For cloud services, you should use [Get-AzureService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/servicemanagement/azure/get-azureservice?view=azuresmps-4.0.0) to fetch the details. Then you can use the related properties to determine if it's stopped or not.

If you receive some errors when running this cmdlet, please use `Add-AzureAccount` cmdlet first.

The test result:

[image]